# Troubleshooting post topojson installation

Tags: javascript, terminal, d3.js

I've installed topojson w/ homebrew and am working on the same tutorial as the user in the post [Troubleshooting topojson installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173853/troubleshooting-topojson-installation) but am not getting any result when I call

```
which topojson

which ogr2ogr
prints  /usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr
```

But I'm getting nothing with which topojson despite just having successfully installed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is probably that the binary for topojson is not in your $PATH (unless you got an error message when installing it). Check the location given in the tutorial, i.e. type the full path.

Comment: Thanks, I did find that to be the issue.  I am supposed to prepend the following to my Path environment:  

/usr/local/share/npm/bin

This will allow npm installed binaries to be picked up. Any good resources for how to do that?

Comment: add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to your `.bashrc` or equivalent if you're using a different shell.

Comment: Cool also found this helpful little post for modifying Path environment in an editor http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.UVd0cqtVBO8.